# filling text file with dates

Tags: python, date, file-io

i would like to file my file with a dates, and i have 02 problems:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

def perdelta(start, end, delta):
    curr = start
    while curr < end:
        yield curr
        curr += delta


fo = open("dattes.txt","wb")
for result in perdelta(date(2011, 10, 10), date(2011, 12, 12), timedelta(days=4)):
    fo.write(result)


fo.close()
```

1- i am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\test\date.txt", line 12, in 
>           fo.write(result)
>       TypeError: must be string or buffer, not datetime.date

2-i would like that the output date would be contiguous (without '-' between day,month and year)

Answer (score 2):

One change will solve both problems:

```
fo.write(result.strftime('%Y%m%d\n'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [datetime.date.strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to format date.

You may want to write newline(`'\n'`) inbetween if you don't want `201110102011101420111018....`.

So,

```
...
for result in perdelta(date(2011, 10, 10), date(2011, 12, 12), timedelta(days=4)):
    fo.write(result.strftime('%Y%m%d\n'))
....
```

alternative

```
...
for result in perdelta(date(2011, 10, 10), date(2011, 12, 12), timedelta(days=4)):
    fo.write('{0:%Y%m%d}\n', result)
...
```

Comment: Surely if you want a newline, just append it in the strftime format string, rather than calling write a second time for the newline alone.

Comment: @user2586513, Then, try `\r\n` instead of `\n`.